# sysenter_entry(): "movl (%ebp), %ebp" What is the meaning

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, x86, system-calls

During the process of the Sysenter fast system call in Linux 2.6.11, before entering Ring0, the VDSO wrapper uses `pushl %EBP; MOVL %ESP, %EBP`, indicating that the address of the user attitude stack with EBP is used.  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.11/source/arch/i386/kernel/vsyscall-sysenter.S#L19

The kernel stack, and the ESP (that is, the address of the user state stack) was pushed into the kernel stack in the subsequent process, but then there was a `MOVL (%EBP), %EBP` in the `sysenter` entry point. (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.11/source/arch/i386/kernel/entry.S#L192)

Shouldn't the EBP register point to the kernel stack at this time? Or is there any other explanation?

My understanding is that this EBP still points to the user stack. At this time, the method is to point EBP to the state of the user stack before interrupted.

Answer (score 4):

EBP still points at the user-space stack.  The kernel entry point hasn't modified it yet, that's why the comment right before that `mov (%ebp), %ebp` says "Load the potential sixth argument from user stack."

EBP is where the 6th arg gets passed in the `int 0x80` ABI.  That's also why the user-space VDSO code that runs before `sysenter` pushes EBP, then copies ESP to EBP so 1. the kernel can restore the user-space stack pointer, and 2. so the kernel has a pointer to that arg that didn't fit in a register.  (6 args plus a call number in EAX)

[`sysenter` itself](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sysenter) overwrites ESP (with a fixed value from an MSR, `IA32_SYSENTER_ESP`).  Linux chooses to use a load in the sysenter entry point to get the kernel stack for the current task rather than update the MSR on every context switch.  Either way, the user-space value of ESP is overwritten.

This stack switch stuff is why interrupts are re-enabled (`sti`) only after the kernel loads a new ESP.  (`sysenter` clears IF, disabling interrupts before any kernel instructions execute.)

This is why EBP isn't available to hold the 6th system-call argument; the sysenter entry point's ABI treats it as the user-space stack pointer, with the item on the top of the stack being the 6th arg.